# Excel Query - Deleting Column Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In our team roster, we are trying to remove the shifts of people, who are away on a given day. For e.g. in the screenshot for 25th May 2017 entry, Leo is away. What formula/option/code can I use in the lines above, so that all of the Leo's shifts are automatically deleted - based on the manual entry in this "Away" Column.

[image: This is the link to the screenshot of roster]

Comment: The `away` row is manually populated, correct?

Comment: Yes, Away row is manually populated Josan. Thanks.

Comment: What formula, etc, are in the current lines above?  Or are they just hardcoded values, in which case it's going to be hard to replace them with a formula (but it would possibly be possible to generate new rows based on the original lines, plus the "away" line)

Comment: Either way is fine, either formula above or to generate new rows based on the original lines and the "away" values. How to generate new rows, based on these values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using Excel VBA.

First, the contents of the original roster (named "Master") are copied to a new worksheet "Updated Roster".  This lets you keep an unchanged copy of the original roster, in case you later **remove** a name from the "Away" row and need to re-apply the updates.

Next, the first column is scanned to locate the "Away:" row.

Finally, for each of the remaining columns, the list of "away" names is loaded into an array.

Then, each "away" name is processed one at a time.  Each occurrence of the name is removed from each row of the roster by matching against regular expressions and then replacing with either a comma or nothing, as appropriate.

```
Option Explicit

Dim AwayRowNbr As Long

Sub UpdateRoster()

  Dim UpdatedRoster As Worksheet
  Dim RowNbr As Long
  Dim ColNbr As Long
  Dim MaxColNbr As Long
  Dim MaxRowNbr As Long

  ' Insert new "Updated Roster" worksheet
  Set UpdatedRoster = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
  UpdatedRoster.Name = "Updated Roster"

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Updated Roster")

    ' Copy contents of "Master" worksheet to "Updated Roster"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Cells.Copy Destination:=.Cells

    ' Locate "Away" row, and determine last column with data
    AwayRowNbr = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="Away:", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    MaxColNbr = .Cells(AwayRowNbr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For ColNbr = 2 To MaxColNbr
      Call RemoveNames(.Cells(AwayRowNbr, ColNbr).Value, ColNbr)
    Next ColNbr

  End With

End Sub

Sub RemoveNames(AwayNames As String, ColNbr As Long)

   Dim AwayName() As String
   Dim Name As String
   Dim NameIdx As Integer
   Dim RegEx As Object
   Dim RowNbr As Long
   Dim MaxRowNbr As Long
   Dim BeforeReplace As String
   Dim AfterReplace As String

   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Updated Roster")

     ' Create regular expression object
     Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
     RegEx.Global = False

     ' Load "away" names into a String array
     AwayName() = Split(AwayNames, ",")

     ' Determine last row with data
     MaxRowNbr = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColNbr).End(xlUp).Row

     ' Process each "away" name
     For NameIdx = LBound(AwayName) To UBound(AwayName)
       Name = Trim(AwayName(NameIdx))
       For RowNbr = 2 To MaxRowNbr
         If RowNbr <> AwayRowNbr Then

           AfterReplace = .Cells(RowNbr, ColNbr).Value

           ' Remove name if delimited by commas
           RegEx.Pattern = ", *" & Name & " *,"
           Do
             BeforeReplace = AfterReplace
             AfterReplace = RegEx.Replace(BeforeReplace, ",")
           Loop Until BeforeReplace = AfterReplace

           ' Remove name if at beginning or end of cell
           RegEx.Pattern = "(^ *" & Name & " *,)|(, *" & Name & " *$)|(^ *" & Name & " *$)"
           Do
             BeforeReplace = AfterReplace
             AfterReplace = RegEx.Replace(BeforeReplace, "")
           Loop Until BeforeReplace = AfterReplace

           .Cells(RowNbr, ColNbr).Value = AfterReplace

         End If
       Next RowNbr
     Next NameIdx

   End With

End Sub
```